# CrystalReport en servidor iis no funciona - ASP:NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, iis, crystal-reports

buenas amigos, les informo que tengo un problema con `Crystal Report` en un servidor `IIS`.

Antes de publicar si me funciona, pero al momento de montarlo en el `Servidor IIS` me da este error

> El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada. Descripción:
>   Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el
>   seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y
>   dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.

**Error de código fuente:**

> Se ha generado una excepción no controlada durante la ejecución de la
>   solicitud Web actual. La información sobre el origen y la ubicación de
>   la excepción pueden identificarse utilizando la excepción del
>   seguimiento de la pila siguiente.

**Seguimiento de la pila:**

```
[COMException (0x80004005): El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) +1140
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) +655
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportOptions options) +111
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType formatType) +98
   wSicavWeb.Controllers.Liquidacion.CotizacionController.ExportReport(Int32 id) in c:\Users\MichelRemoto\Desktop\Agencia 2017\wSicavWebMichel\wSicavWeb\Controllers\Liquidacion\CotizacionController.cs:52
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765121
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

---

- Instale los parches de `SAP` de cristal.
- Verifique la ruta y es la misma(incluso si quito el reporte de la dirección me da el error de que no esta).
- El reporte hace la vista si entro directamente en él.
- Funciona en la solución, pero no en el `IIS`

Comment: ¿Cómo haces el deploy?

Comment: disculpa a que te refieres con el deploy? el codigo?

la aplicacion en el iis funciona, lo unico que no es cuando voy a pedir el reporte y esto solo pasa en el iis, en el proyecto no. Gracias de antemano

Comment: sucede que cuando hay una puesta en producción (deploy) las rutas cambian, en este caso, el sistema ya dejó de estar en: c:\Users\MichelRemoto\Desktop\Agencia 2017\wSicavWebMichel\wSicavWeb\Controllers\Liquidacion\CotizacionController.cs y ahora se encuentra en C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<algunaCarpetaPorAqui>

Comment: ahh ok ... sabes que había pensando en eso... en hacer el deploy en C:\ a ver como me va  gracias

Comment: no hace diferencia  amigo.. ademas que al hacer el deploy no se lee por controllers

Comment: por eso mismo la pregunta: ¿Cómo haces el deploy?

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Answer (score 1):

te comento como lo hago.

1.- creo una variable con la ruta donde estan los archivos

```
  string DirectorioReportesRelativo = "~/Reportes/Apertura/";
```

2.- creo al ruta con el  nombre del archivo

```
 string urlArchivo = string.Format("{0}.{1}", "ValOfertasDetalle", "rpt");

            string FullPathReport = string.Format("{0}{1}",
                                    this.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(DirectorioReportesRelativo),
                                     urlArchivo);

            report.FileName = FullPathReport;
```

y al final cargo el archivo.

```
report.Load();
```

Answer (score 0):

En este método:

*wSicavWeb.Controllers.Liquidacion.CotizacionController.ExportReport*

No esa encontrando la ruta fisica del reporte!

Acuerdate que en ASP.NET para obtener el path fisico de donde se encuentra un archivo dentro de la app web debes utilizar [HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var rpt = new ReportDocument();    
//Localizar el path del reporte
rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/DemoCrystalReport.rpt"));
```

¿Podrías colocar parte del codigo que lees el reporte para ver como lo obtienes? Asi te podremos ayudar mejor

Comment: rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reportes"), "ww_Cotizacion.rpt"));           rd.SetDataSource(db.Tbl_Cotizacion.Where(a=>a.id==id).ToList());
rd.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "Ws1c4v321");
            
  Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return File(stream, "application/pdf");

Comment: este es el link de donde tome el ejemplo... lo hice tal cual y como les digo.. sirve pero al montarlo en el iis me da el error   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yLHhsTjK68

Comment: quitale Path.Combine y concatena manualmente como te lo ha puesto Jose A. Deberías en cualquier caso comprobar que la ruta que te devuelve en producción exista realmente

Comment: [Server.MapPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.7.2) ya hace un combinación/concatenación del path dale una mirada a  la doc. Pero seria bueno que nos informes si el path que arma es el correcto (ejemplo var path = Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/ww_Cotizacion.rpt")). Avisanos o pon un ejempo si en dicho path fisico que se arma esta el reporte